# Store similar keys in list of dictionaries as same column in CSV file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

Suppose I have the following list of dictionary:

```
citation = [{'ID':'101',
             'SENTENCE':'This is a theory sample from a book.'
             'AUTHOR':'ALEX B.',
             'AUTHOR1':'JOHN K.',
             'TITLE':'BASIC PROGRAMMING',
             'URL':'an.example.com',
             'YEAR':'2010'},
            {'ID':'102',
             'SENTENCE':'This is a theory from book 1 and book 2',
             'AUTHOR':'MARINA E.',
             'TITLE':'BE A GOOD PROGRAMMER',
             'YEAR':'2011',
             'AUTHOR1':'STEVE M.',
             'AUTHOR2':'DIANE L.',
             'TITLE1':'I AM AN ENGINEER',
             'YEAR1':'2013',
             'VOLUME':'10'},
            {.. other data...},
           ]
```

I need to save this list of dictionary into `csv` file. If the key in the dictionary is similar (`AUTHOR = AUTHOR1 = AUTHOR2, TITLE = TITLE1 = TITLE2` etc.), then put in the same column without number in the column name (`AUTHOR, TITLE, YEAR`). If the data value in a column more than one, they should be separated by a semicolon (`;`). Also, the key names and their order in each dictionary are sometimes different from the other dictionaries in the list.

This is my code, but it doesn't work because the similar keys in the dictionary are stored as different fieldnames:

```
outpath = 'mycitation.csv'
outfile = open(outpath, 'w')

fields = (list(set(k for d in citation for k in d)))
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=field, dialect='excel')

writer.writeheader()
for row in citation:
    writer.writerow(row)
outfile.close()
```

The output I need to achieve in the `csv` file:

```
ID  | SENTENCE                                | AUTHOR                      | TITLE                                  | YEAR       | URL             | VOLUME 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
101 | This is a theory sample from a book.    | ALEX B.;JOHN K.             | BASIC PROGRAMMING                      | 2010       | an.example.com  |
102 | This is a theory from book 1 and book 2 | MARINA E.;STEVE M.;DIANE L. | BE A GOOD PROGRAMMER; I AM AN ENGINEER | 2011; 2013 |                 | 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict.get()` method combined with string formatting.

```
for i in citation:
    authors = [i.get("AUTHOR","")]
    titles = [i.get("TITLE","")]
    for x in range(1,10):
        authors.append(i.get("AUTHOR{}".format(x),""))
        titles.append(i.get("TITLE{}".format(x),""))
    a_result,t_result = ";".join(a for a in authors if a),"; ".join(t for t in titles if t)
    print (a_result+"|"+t_result)
```

Result:

```
ALEX B.;JOHN K.|BASIC PROGRAMMING
MARINA E.;STEVE M.;DIANE L.|BE A GOOD PROGRAMMER; I AM AN ENGINEER
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks [Henry Yik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9284423/henry-yik)